# If value exists in array, end, and restart with next array value

Tags: php, arrays

All day I've been trying to achieve the following with PHP:

Update: This is the code I'm using, please read the message in between

```
  <?php

    include ('acs_params.php'); 

    $acs_value_based = array(25, 30, 35, 40, 45, 50, 60, 70);
    $acs_types = array("$add_total","$done_total");

        print_r($acs_id);

    foreach ( $acs_value_based as &$value ) {
    foreach ( $acs_types as &$counters) { 

    if ($counters >= $value) {    

    if ($acs_types[0] == $counters) {$acs_types1 = '1'; $acs_name = 'Tasker'; $acs_action = 'adding';}
    if ($acs_types[1] == $counters) {$acs_types1 = '2'; $acs_name = 'Completer'; $acs_action = 'completing';}

    if ($value == '25') { $acs_lvl = '1'; $acs_id = '25';}
    if ($value == '30') { $acs_lvl = '2'; $acs_id = '30';}
    if ($value == '35') { $acs_lvl = '3'; $acs_id = '35';}

    $acs_exists = $acs_types1 . $acs_id;
```

Over here it should check if this array print_r($acs_id); contains the value of 
$acs_exists. if the value already exists the following code should not be executed, 
 instead, the script should start again at the beginning but then with the second value of 
 the array print_r($acs_id);. It the value is not existing yet, then continue with the queries. (I hope my goal is clear).

```
   mysql_query("INSERT INTO users_log(id, log, userid, date, points, action) VALUES

(id, 'achievement 1', '$username', '$currenttime', '0', '8') ");

    mysql_query("INSERT INTO users_achievements(id, userid, acs_id, date) VALUES

(id, '$username', '$acs_types1$acs_id', '$currenttime') ");

    ?>
```

Comment: What code have you written so far?

Comment: I don't really understand what it is you're trying to do. Could you give an example?

Comment: please re-read updated question :)

Comment: I still don't understand. Why do you keep talking about "restarting the script, but with the second value of the array"??? What's wrong with a simple loop? Still unclear … Is `$acs_exists` a string? why is the current id (`$acs_id`) appended to it? what is `$acs_types1`?

Answer (score 0):

<strike>This sounds to simple, but I'll give it a shot:</strike>

```
// if $acs_exist is not in the array $acs_id, execute script, otherwise do nothing
if(!in_array($acs_exist, $acs_id)) {
  // do whatever you want 
}
```

I'm still poking in the dark here …

```
foreach($acs_id => $id) {
  if($acs_id == $acs_exist) { // already exists
  } else { // does not exist yet, insert into db
    // your code: INSERT INTO table (column, …) VALUES(:acs_id, …)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach ($acs_id as $item) {

  if ($item == $acs_exist) continue;

  // continue with the script (query etc)

}
```

Is that what you're after?

Comment: @MaartenHartman Is `$acs_id` and array? Can you show a `print_r()` of it? Also, what do `$add_total` and `$done_total` contain?